# VBA - Find value from range of formulas

Tags: vba, excel, types, find, range

I have this line of code that is supposed to find the same value in a range:

```
Set RowN = oldDashboard.Sheets("Dom").Range("F1:F1000").Find(this.Sheets("Domestic").Range("A" & i).Value)
```

It works fine when my range is composed of values but when the range is composed of **formulas** it does not work. I tried putting .Value after Range("F1: F1000") but it brings an error. I think the answer is fairly simple but I cannot figure it out.

Thanks

Comment: would it work if you change at last .value to .formulas

Comment: no it does not, i am trying to find the value of Range A,  as the outcome of the formula in Range F1 : F1000

Comment: Range A is always values and ranges F is formulas

Comment: what is `this`? Do you mean `thisWorkbook` or do you have it declared as Worksheet-Variable or is it a typo? Anyhow, in any case I would strongly suggest to split such a command into several lines, for example first read the `value` into a variable and put this as parameter into the `Find`-command.

Comment: You are not using all arguments that .Find method offers. It is possible to search by formula (`xlFormulas`) or values(`xlValues`) `Set RowN = oldDashboard.Sheets("Dom").Range("F1:F1000").Find(What:=Sheets("Domestic").Range("A" & i).Value, LookIn:=xlFormulas)`

Comment: @ShrivallabhaRedij thanks, this seems to the way to answer my problem. Saying i put `Lookin:= xlValues` it will search the values of range `"F1:F100"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using all arguments that .Find method offers.

It is possible to search by formula (`xlFormulas`) or values(`xlValues`)

Example:

`Set RowN = oldDashboard.Sheets("Dom").Range("F1:F1000").Find(What:=Shee‌​ts("Domestic").Range‌​("A" & i).Value, LookIn:=xlFormulas)`